# Group by запрос mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть записи с одинаковыми данными, отличается только одно поле: 
[image: img]

Как сделать одним запросом группировку по id, а во втором столбце получить все значения через запятую

Answer (score 2):

Используйте агрегатную функцию `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT
  id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM
  my_table
GROUP BY
  id
```

Comment: Перед тем как давать ответ на элементарный вопрос попробуйте за автора вопроса провести поискю таких ответов на сайте 100500 штук, нет смысла плодить еще